# Possible bug when using UNC filenames in SQL Server 2017 python scripts?

Tags: python, sql-server

I am converting one of my Python scripts that gets daily use to run inside of a SQL Server 2017 Agent job and finding that I cannot get any UNC filenames to work in Python scripts running in SQL Server.

In the following code, there are two sections, both pointing at the same file on the host machine.  The first uses a UNC pathname, the second, a local pathname.  When run as a standard Python script, both find the file and perform the copy.  In SQL Server 2017, however, it does NOT find the UNC filename and only executes the exists and copyfile correctly with the local pathname.  Obviously, this is just to demonstrate the problem as my production code must access files on another server.

Has anyone else run into this issue and know if it is a reported bug and if there is a workaround?

```
declare @PythonScript       nvarchar(max);

set @PythonScript = N'
from shutil import copyfile
import os.path
from pathlib import Path, PureWindowsPath

fileToSearch = "\\\\DEVSQL002\\Downloads\\suspense_payments.txt"
backFile = "\\\\DEVSQL002\\Downloads\\suspense_payments.bak"
if os.path.exists(fileToSearch):
    print("File exists")
    copyfile(fileToSearch, backFile)
    print("copyfile successful")
else:
    print("File does not exist.")

fileToSearch = "f:\\Downloads\\suspense_payments.txt"
backFile = "f:\\Downloads\\suspense_payments.bak"
if os.path.exists(fileToSearch):
    print("File exists")
    copyfile(fileToSearch, backFile)
    print("copyfile successful")
else:
    print("File does not exist.")
'

execute sp_execute_external_script @language = N'Python', 
@script = @PythonScript
```

STDOUT message(s) from external script: 
File does not exist.
File exists
copyfile successful

Comment: How is the script running e.g. is it via SQL Agent? This has some signs of a permissions issue and needing it to run under the context of a Windows domain account.